# C: Getting the default gateway for an IP address on BSD

Tags: c, sockets, bsd

I am trying to find a way to get default gateway for an IPv4 address in C.  I have created code that iterates through all of the IP addresses via the getifaddrs() function. This gives me a list of valid IPs, and I filter out those that start with 127.* and 169.*.  I then want to get the gateway for that IP address, but I've come across some hiccups (net/route.c source code is difficult to understand without context)

Does a function exist that allows me to pass an IP address and get the gateway for that IP address?

Comment: If you haven't tried it yet, using  p_rttables found in /usr/src/sbin/route/show.c helps printing out the default gateway.